# mysql win loss records and joining three tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join three tables together and it's gotten a little complicated.  This is what I have. It was working fine before trying to select the team name. Also, if anyone knows how to calculate the wins and losses more effectively that would be helpful.

```
$sql = '
    SELECT u.name, 
        t.name AS team, 
        SUM(
             CASE WHEN (g.awayScore > g.homeScore AND g.away=u.team) 
                 OR (g.homeScore > g.awayScore AND g.home=u.team) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS wins,
        SUM(
             CASE WHEN (g.awayScore < g.homeScore AND g.away=u.team) 
                 OR (g.homeScore < g.awayScore AND g.home=u.team) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses
      FROM game AS g
      JOIN user AS u ON g.away = u.team OR g.home = u.team
      JOIN team AS t ON g.away=t.id OR g.home=t.id
      GROUP BY u.name
    ';
```

Comment: What is the query returning and how does this differ from what is desired?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are people here that want to help you; but many are busy with other things, and you may need to wait to get a good answer. Please don't be put off by the downvoters; they have a reason for what they do, and its not about you.) I think the problem in your query is fairly obvious. I hope you find an answer that explains it in a way that is helpful to you, that helps you understand. Again, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to join `team` to the `user`, not the `game`. I expect that `user` table has a `team_id` (or `team`) column which is a foreign key `references team(id)`.

I think the only change needed in your query is one line. Just change this:

```
JOIN team AS t ON g.away=t.id OR g.home=t.id
```

to

```
JOIN team AS t ON t.id = u.team
```

That should be sufficient to fix the problem.

---

But I'd write the query a bit differently. Something like this:

```
SELECT u.name
     , t.name AS team
     , SUM(
         CASE WHEN (g.awayScore > g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                OR (g.homeScore > g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id) 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS wins
     , SUM(
         CASE WHEN (g.awayScore < g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                OR (g.homeScore < g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS losses
  FROM user u
  JOIN team t ON t.id = u.team
  JOIN game g ON g.away = t.id OR g.home = t.id
 GROUP
    BY u.name
     , t.name
```

**NOTES**

I'd start with the user table, that's what we really want to return.  (If we wanted to return zeros for users in teams that weren't in any game, then we'd be looking at doing an OUTER JOIN, and I just always write LEFT JOINS.)

Next, I'd get the team associated with each user.

Then, I'd join to the game.  It's a bit tricky here, because you're doubling up the rows from game, one to match the away team, one to match the home team.  That's also going the multiply the rows, one for each user on the team. But we need that, because we're going to sum them all up.

Writing the query this way makes it fairly easy just to get the scores by team, without returning the user:

```
SELECT t.name AS team
     , SUM(
         CASE WHEN (g.awayScore > g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                OR (g.homeScore > g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id) 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS wins
     , SUM(
         CASE WHEN (g.awayScore < g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                OR (g.homeScore < g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS losses
  FROM team t
  JOIN game g ON g.away = t.id OR g.home = t.id
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

For large sets, that could be a rather large number of rows, that first query could generate a lot of rows, because the rows for each team are getting duplicated for each user on a team.

So, another approach might be to calculate the team scores first, then join to user. But that's going to require a derived table, which is overhead for generating a temporary MyISAM table, and then querying from that.  (If this is a track team with dozens of users, this might be more efficient. But if its teams of two (beach volleyball?) it likely won't improve performance.

If we take the team scores query above, we can wrap that in parens and use it like a table. We also want to include the id column from the team table, so we can join that to the users table in the outer query:

```
SELECT u.name
     , s.name AS team
  FROM user u 
  JOIN ( SELECT t.id
              , t.name
              , SUM(
                  CASE WHEN (g.awayScore > g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                         OR (g.homeScore > g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id) 
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ) AS wins
              , SUM(
                  CASE WHEN (g.awayScore < g.homeScore AND g.away=t.id)
                         OR (g.homeScore < g.awayScore AND g.home=t.id)
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ) AS losses
           FROM team t
           JOIN game g ON g.away = t.id OR g.home = t.id
          GROUP BY t.id, t.name
       ) s
    ON s.id = u.team
```

The inline view (assigned an alias of s) is basically the same as the previous "team scores" query. We include the team.id column so we can join that to the user table, in the outer query.

-- another alternative approach:

```
SELECT u.name
     , t.name AS team
     , SUM(g.wins) AS wins
     , SUM(g.losses) AS losses
  FROM user u
  JOIN team t ON t.id = u.team
  JOIN ( SELECT gh.home AS team
              , SUM(IF(gh.homeScore > gh.awayScore,1,0)) AS wins
              , SUM(IF(gh.homeScore < gh.awayScore,1,0)) AS losses
           FROM game gh
          GROUP BY gh.home
          UNION ALL
         SELECT ga.away AS team
              , SUM(IF(ga.awayScore > ga.homeScore,1,0)) AS wins
              , SUM(IF(ga.awayScore < ga.homeScore,1,0)) AS losses
           FROM game ga
          GROUP BY ga.away
       ) g
    ON g.team = t.id
 GROUP
    BY u.name
     , t.name
```

The inline view (assigned an alias of g above) is calculating home wins and losses and away wins and losses separately, and then concatenating them together. The query could be tweaked a bit, if you wanted to return separately home_wins, home_losses, away_wins, and away_losses. And these could be added together in the outer query to get total wins and losses.